# Django Calculate Average From Model Fields and Store in Another Model

Tags: python, django

I have a model where I hold at least 3 scores, but which in the future may hold more. The scores can be blank or contain a value, meaning different schools can have a different number of entries.

My challenge is I'd like then to have a field that's based off a function of the above scores so I can call this on my views rather than have to calculate it every time.

I'm trying to find the best way to ensure that the main score is calculated and saved every time one of the contributing scores is updated, but only then.

```
class Marks(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    marks_2016 = models.DecimalField(name='2016 Marks', max_digits=12, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)
    marks_2017 = models.DecimalField(name='2017 Marks', max_digits=12, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)
    marks_2018 = models.DecimalField(name='2018 Marks', max_digits=12, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school.name

class Score(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school
```

Comment: This is really bad design. You should have another table called something like `YearScore` that has fields `year`, `score`, and a foreign key field that points to a `Marks` object. This way, different `Marks` objects  can have different `YearScore`s and the average can be calculated easily. You also won't have to keep adding new columns for each year.

Comment: Yeah, I have also been doubting that my design is the best here. Note though that each school can only have one score per year, if present. But I also need to add a field every new year. 

But the total score is a function of all of a school's scores eg marks_2016+marks_2017+marks+2018+marks_2019+marks_2020...

Comment: I think I now get it - I should have "school" "marks" and "year" as my fields so that I do not have to change my program with the addition of every new year. Thanks.